# Auto Hide in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, the *pin* icon allows me to auto hide a tab that is docked to the left or to the right of my central code tab.

[image]

Works great.

I also have a tab docked below my central code tab.  There is no Auto Hide feature.  There are *pins*, but the tool tip for them states *Toggle pin status* (not clear to me what that "status" does).

[image]

How can I auto-hide my tab below the central code tab (or individual windows within that tab) such that the tab / component windows are quickly accessible as Solution Explorer is if I Auto Hide it?

Or, do tabs docked left/right behave fundamentally differently than tabs docked below the central code tab?

Comment: In the Visual Studio 2012 RTM, the tooltip reads "Auto Hide."  Does the pane not switch to auto-hide mode when you toggle the pin status?

Comment: I'm using RTM (never installed Beta or RC).  The first screenshot does switch to auto hide mode (desired behavior).  The second screenshot does not have an "auto hide" pin at all and I see no way to auto hide the tab or tab components (windows?) that are docked at the bottom.

Comment: Oh, I see.  It looks like the tool window is docked as a document.  If you grab it by its tab and drag, a drag target should appear at the bottom of the shell window; if you drag the tab there, it should dock as a tool pane, which will let you auto-hide it.  Does that work?

Comment: Sort of... it then spans across the entire lower screen.  I would prefer that the left/right columns extend all the way down.  However, if that's the only option, it's good enough.  If you want to change your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: That should be what [this drag target does.](http://oi49.tinypic.com/2imaxqv.jpg)  No?

Comment: When you drag and drop, you should get two options for a bottom pane. The lower one pins it across the entire screen, the one above that pins it to the middle window.

Comment: @aclear16: When I pin to the middle window, I get the behavior where there is no "Auto Hide" option.